# Utilisation de "en" en tant qu'un sujet

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en

Quelle est l’utilisation de **en** dans ces exemples :

> Troisièmement, **en** apprendre plus sur leur nature.

> ...et **en** apprendre plus sur lui même

Est-il correct d'utiliser **en** comme ça, ou faut-il utiliser **on**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ces phrases sont correctes.

Par contre, dans tes exemples *en* n'est pas un sujet. Le verbe est à l'infinitif donc n'a pas pas de sujet, et si on le conjuguait on aurait :

> **Je** veux **en** apprendre plus sur leur nature.

Ici le sujet est *je*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!